# In this by-CodeFirst-EF-generated schema, lazy loading is working only on 2 of the 3 properties. Isn't that inconsistent?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**SOLUTION**:

To make lazy loading work i had to do a few things:

- make sure EF could override my Models:

  - make the *navigation properties* (basically every property that has one of my models as a type) `virtual`
  - make the model-classes `public`
- Add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to the Connection String, so that my deferred LINQ-queries get executed

**ORIGINAL PROBLEM**:

Using CodeFirst, I have defined classes and these are the tables that are created from it. 
After some reading, I now think I understand lazy loading and that it is enabled by default. Hence I don't understand why - coming from `EetWaarnemingen` - I need `.Include("Aap")` to make my queries work, while I don't need them for `VoedingsProducten` or `Waarnemers`.

[image: CodeFirst generated db-schema]

When I do:

```
var alleBananen =
            from b in db.EetWaarnemingen
            where b.VoedingsProduct.Naam == "Banaan"
            select b;
```

Then this works:

```
Console.WriteLine(alleBananen.First().Tijdstip.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(alleBananen.First().VoedingsProduct.Naam);
```

But this **does not**:

```
Console.WriteLine(alleBananen.First().Aap.Naam);
```

*The error is `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`*

If I add an `.Include("Aap")` like so:

```
var alleBananen =
            from b in db.EetWaarnemingen.Include("Aap")
            where b.VoedingsProduct.Naam == "Banaan"
            select b;
```

Then all 3 statements work just fine.

I cannot really see much difference between `VoedingsProduct` and `Aap`, coming from `EetWaarnemingen`.

> Excuse me for the Dutch language but I spent too much time with it already to translate... If you're curious, it's about observing (waarnemen) monkeys (apen) and their food- and friend-habits.

For completeness, here are the models. I didn't use virtual, would that make a difference?

```
[Table("Apen")]
class Aap
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public DateTime Geboortedatum { get; set; }
}

[Table("VoedingsProducten")]
class VoedingsProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public int Energiewaarde { get; set; }
}

class Waarnemer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
}

[Table("EetWaarnemingen")]
class EetWaarneming
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Waarnemer Waarnemer { get; set; }
    public DateTime Tijdstip { get; set; }
    public Aap Aap { get; set; }
    public VoedingsProduct VoedingsProduct { get; set; }
}

[Table("VriendWaarnemingen")]
class VriendWaarneming
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Waarnemer Waarnemer { get; set; }
    public DateTime Tijdstip { get; set; }
    public Aap Aap { get; set; }
    public Aap Vriend { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I notice that if I have used `.Include("Aap").Include("Vriend")` on an earlier query, the above queries **do** work. That makes it even more strange for me, especially since i put the earlier includes behind `VriendWaarnemingen` and not behind `EetWaarnemingen` as in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loading relies on your navigation properties being marked with the `virtual` keyword. This allows Entity Framework to create a helper class, that derives from yours, but overrides the property getter.

Lazy loading will not work for any non-virtual navigation property. However, if the referenced entities are already loaded in the context for other reasons, it is possible that the navigation property got set already, even though it is non-virtual. This will, by chance, be what's happening for two of your three properties, and you can verify that by creating a new context (in which no entities are loaded) for each of your queries.

Comment: I have tried to do `virtual public Aap Aap {get; set;}` in `EetWaarnemingen` and couldn't see any difference.

Comment: But your comment about the **context** was very useful! I indeed verified it is not working for the other 2 in a fresh context.

Comment: @hansvb There are some other reasons why lazy loading might not work, but they depend on information that's not in your question. The first things to check I can think of: firstly, make sure lazy loading isn't simply disabled. Secondly, make sure the entities you've got loaded in your context do use the EF-generated derived classes (don't ever use `new Aap()` directly). Third, consistently use `virtual` for all navigation properties, not just the one you want lazy loading to work for. (I don't know for sure if that last one is a hard requirement.)

Comment: In my Seed()-method I have done a few `new Aap()`'s, as to refer to them in a call to AddOrUpdate(...). That's not allowed?

Comment: @hansvb It's allowed, but at the cost of having lazy loading not work for that entity (even though it should work if you re-retrieve the entity in a brand new context). To have that work automatically, you need to use `objectContext.CreateObject<Aap>()` / `dbContext.Apen.Create()` instead of `new Aap()`, to give Entity Framework the chance to use its own type (the type that includes the support for lazy loading) in `Aap`'s place.